# Present .sheet from top and not from the bottom

Tags: swift, swiftui

I have this basic `.sheet` in `SwiftUI`. Is it possible to make it draggable from the `top` instead from the `bottom`?

```
struct MySheet: View {
   @State private var show = true

   var body: some View {
       VStack {

       }
       .sheet(isPresented: $show) {
           Text("Sheet")
            .presentationDetents([.medium, .large])
       }

   }
}
```

Comment: [Related](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57005230/custom-modal-transitions-in-swiftui)

Answer (score 0):

I doubt this is natively implemented in SwiftUI however you could implement your own sheet presentation as a view and add an `.animation(from: .top)`, even though this will be pain to create a whole navigation system for that but at least it will be `reusable` and you may end up dumping SwiftUI's navigation system completely and using your own.